# Elixir ArgumentError in Enum.reduce with String concatenation

Tags: elixir

When passing the string "word", I'm trying to print "W-oo-rrr-dddd" (it's a kata).

```
String.graphemes(word) |> Enum.with_index(1) |> Enum.reduce(
  fn
    ({a, 1}, _) -> String.capitalize(a)
    ({a, i}, acc) -> acc <> "-" <> String.pad_trailing(String.capitalize(a), i, String.downcase(a))
  end
)
```

But I get:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
lib/katas.ex:12: anonymous fn/2 in Katas.accum/1
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:1755: Enum."-reduce/2-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
lib/katas.ex:9: Katas.accum/1
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir) lib/code.ex:170: Code.eval_string/3
```

However, if I take the accumulator concatenation out of the second function match, the error is not raised (although the code now is wrong)

```
String.graphemes("word") |> Enum.with_index(1) |> Enum.reduce(
  fn
    ({a, 1}, _) -> String.capitalize(a)
    ({a, i}, _) -> String.pad_trailing(String.capitalize(a), i, String.downcase(a))
  end
)
```

However, string concatenation seems to be working just fine:

```
iex(73)> Enum.reduce(["StringA", "StringB"], fn(x, acc) -> acc <> "-" <> x end)
"StringA-StringB"
```

So, how can I make the first piece of code work?
Thanks

Comment: It seems like that the `String.capitalize/1` causing issues within your reduce fn (not sure why). If you remove that, and keep if as `String.pad_trailing(a, i, a)`, it works just fine (tested in 1.4.4). Could you give that a go?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the initial value of the accumulator to `""`, otherwise it's set to the first item of the list, which means your accumulator starts off with a tuple `{"w", 1}`, and you get the argument error when you try to use it as a string.

```
word = "word"
String.graphemes(word) |> Enum.with_index(1) |> Enum.reduce(
  "",
  fn
    ({a, 1}, _) -> String.capitalize(a)
    ({a, i}, acc) -> acc <> "-" <> String.pad_trailing(String.capitalize(a), i, String.downcase(a))
  end
)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
"W-Oo-Rrr-Dddd"
```

---

I'd also suggest using `Enum.map_join/3` here for more elegant (IMO) code:

```
word = "word"
String.graphemes(word)
|> Enum.with_index(1)
|> Enum.map_join(
  "-",
  fn
    {a, 1} -> String.capitalize(a)
    {a, i} -> String.pad_trailing(String.capitalize(a), i, String.downcase(a))
  end
)
|> IO.inspect
```